# Django - function views do not show up in admindocs

Tags: django, python-3.6

Edit: I'm using Django 1.11, if that makes a difference

I have some function based views in Django that are fairly simple, I followed the instructions here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/ to set it up admindocs and it seems to work just fine for a view given by the Django REST Framework: rest_framework.authtoken.views.ObtainAuthToken

As an example, this is what is generated in admindocs for the above view:

```
/endpoint/auth
View function: rest_framework.authtoken.views.ObtainAuthToken. Name: endpoint.
```

But in the same namespace, the other function based views look like this:

```
/endpoint/config
View function: endpoint.views.WrappedAPIView. Name: endpoint.
```

All of the other function views have the above endpoint.views.WrappedAPIView listed as the view function, and when I click that I obviously get a 404 because that is incorrect and doesn't exist as far as I can tell.

The documentation I followed seems to indicate that function based views should work with admindocs, so I'm just confused on why they're not getting picked up.

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you ever solve this?